# How to get the id of the current item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am editing an item which contains some information, once the item is edited, I need to send the new info to the database through a `post` request.

the object I am working on is named `dealer`, that dealer has an `id`, look at the code

```
if (this.props.dealerData) {
  let dealerProps = this.props.dealerData.dealersData;
  dealerInfo = dealerProps.map((dealer) => {

    return (<div>
          <Card>

            <CardHeader title={dealer.NickName}
                        subtitle={dealer.DealerId} //DEALER ID HERE
                        avatar={dealer.DealerName}/>

              <Button onClick={this._updateDealer} />

          </Card>
        </div>
      );
  })
}
```

that is the data I am sending to the db with this function

```
  _updateDealer = () => {
    UpdateDealerActions.updateDealer({
      DealerId   : // HERE I NEED TO SEND THE DEALER ID,
      DealerName : this.refs.DealerNameEdit.getValue(),
      NickName   : this.refs.NickNameEdit.getValue(),
    });
  }
```

let me explain: you have that collection of items being render here with `dealerInfo`, there is like 30 items/dealers. The `DealerId` is not editable, it is just something you need to send to the DB in order to know which dealer you are editing.

So, in my function `_updateDealer()`, which is the best method to catch the DealerId ?

**EDIT**

this is the part of the code where I am editing with the `refs`

```
<Checkbox value="Active" ref="Active" defaultChecked={true}/>
<TextField ref="DealerNameEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.DealerName} onChange={this._handleUpdateChange.bind(this, 'DealerName')} />
<TextField ref="CardIdEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.CardId} onChange={this._handleUpdateChange.bind(this, 'CardId')} />
<TextField ref="NickNameEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.NickName} onChange={this._handleUpdateChange.bind(this, 'NickName')} />
<TextField ref="LegalIdEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.LegalId} onChange={this._handleUpdateChange.bind(this, 'LegalId')} />
<TextField ref="TypeIdEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.TypeId} onChange={this._handleUpdateChange.bind(this, 'TypeId')} />
```

Comment: @Tushar I put the Reactjs tag already. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the rest of your structure looks like, but I suspect you may run into an issue with your refs since it looks like you're creating a list of editors but just two refs as opposed to n refs...

Comment: @Jonathan that is another part of the code.

Comment: @Jonathan take a look at the edit

Comment: Are those textfields in Card?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, but the DealerId is not editable. it is just info coming from the DB in order for me to render it.

Comment: I'd recommend passing the whole dealer object to Card, let Card render however you want and have Card accept an onChange prop that can notify the rendering parent of changes. If you have multiple uses of card you could create DealerCard  or something for this use case. Right now you've jumbled refs because to the best of my knowledge parents don't get access to a child's refs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the id to the click handler.

```
     <Button onClick={this._updateDealer.bind(this, dealer.DealerId)} />
```

And then in your handler

```
_updateDealer = (DealerId) => {
    UpdateDealerActions.updateDealer({
    DealerId   : DealerId,
    DealerName : this.refs.DealerNameEdit.getValue(),
    NickName   : this.refs.NickNameEdit.getValue(),
  });
}
```

another solution should be:

```
<TextField ref="DealerIdEdit" value={this.state.toEdit.DealerId} />
```

and in the `_updateDealer()`

```
DealerId   : this.refs.DealerIdEdit.getValue()
```

Comment: with this all I am getting is the ID of the last dealer in the collection and not the current one.

Comment: sorry, i had a mistake in the bind.

Comment: accept the edit so I can give you the proper answer.